# Custom Class of UIButton and show it in StoryBoard having enum also

Tags: ios, uibutton, customization

I want to create a sub-class of UIButton. I want to give some extra functionality there. Here in this class i am using the enum also like as UIButtonType in the UIButton class. I want to show this option in the storyboad UI also, from where developer can select the type of custom button class. Please suggest me, how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify your UIButton inherited class as IBDesignable and to add a NSInteger IBInspectable property that will be analyzed by InterfaceBuilder in order to be displayed.

However, Interface Builder can not render a enum type IBInspectable property; that's why the only way to achieve this is an NSInteger property.

Finally you will select a integer value in interface builder for your custom button (0, 1 ... YourEnumMaxValue) that corresponds to the enum value. At last, you just need to implement some code to render your button following the choosen value in IB.

More on LiveRendering : [Creating a Custom View That Renders in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/Chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your precious reply.